# How is fstream / ifstream / ofstream objects convert to bool

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to know, how these objects convert to bool. I mean what the compiler relies on when casting. On bit flags? As I think it works like that: the compiler checks the flags and if !goodbit then returns false else true.
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("someDir.txt");

    if(!file) { \\ Checks the flags? If !goodbit (eofbit, badbit or failbit) return false else true?
        \\some code
    }

    return 0;
```

P.S. I have bad English, sorry

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: As @Asteroids points out, you don't have to guess, you can just look it up in the documentation (why wasn't that the first thing you did btw?).

Comment: for OPs defense, if you dont know what to look for it can be missed easyly, prior to c++11 there wasnt even a conversion to `bool` directly.

Comment: @idclev C++11 is 9+ years old by now. Nobody should be using anything older - most should be using something substantially *newer*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl my point was just that someone new to `c++` may not be aware that they need to look for `operator bool` (and I completely agree to "should" but unfortunately "refereces" that show `C++98` by default still exist)

Comment: @idclev463035818 I partly agree with your point of view (as a noob in c++), but the fact is that I just couldn’t find the information I needed in the documentation myself and therefore I asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler uses the [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to convert the stream to a boolean. In the documentation you can read that `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool`

> Checks whether the stream has no errors.
>
> 1) Returns a null pointer if `fail()` returns `true`, otherwise returns a non-null pointer. This pointer is implicitly convertible to bool and may be used in boolean contexts.
>
> 2) Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns !fail().

There is a really helpful table on the same page that details which bits (`eofbit, failbit, badbit`) result in `fail()` returning true or false.

Comment: Thank you! It's really what i'm looking for