# What does !(cout << ....) mean

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cout

I just came across a code snippet in C++ here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-cpp-tricky-programs/

One of the snippets is basically:

```
if (!(cout << "A")) {
    cout <<" B ";
}
else {
    cout << "C ";
}
```

The output is: "AC"

What exactly does the argument in the if clause mean ?
And how would you word it in regular English ?

My guess is it means: if "A" is not printable, then print "B", but I am not sure.

Also, is this syntax used often ? I think this is the first time I see cout in an argument, though I have seen getc or getch in the argument clause before.

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: `cout << "A"` returns the stream (after printing "A") which is "true" so `!(cout << "A")` is false and thus "C" is printed.

Comment: unfortunately the explanation that comes with the code is completely off "i.e., cout << "geeks" which returns a non-zero value," what?!? that it returns a non-zero value is as relvant as returning a value that is not equal to `1` here :/

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200609/how-is-fstream-ifstream-ofstream-objects-convert-to-bool

Comment: Geeks for Geeks is a very poor quality and misinformation website.

Comment: I prefer to be neutral when it is about others work, but this site makes it difficult to not rant. It is really bad to start with an intro ala "We may come across various tricky programs in our day to day life." and then present weird code examples with wrong explanations. You better choose some other learning material.

Comment: If you come across a tricky program, do what you can to make it less tricky while still meeting the requirements. Some things are just tricky. The rest is someone either fooling themselves or showing off. If you see code like  `x = x << 3 + x + x;` odds are good `x *= 10;` will be just as fast and far less obnoxious. I admit to being more plumber than computer scientist, but in my work if I have to get tricky, I've probably already lost. You don't trust tricky code to keep a plane in the air and on course. You trust the dumbest, stupidest code that does the job.

Comment: That is a great way to put it, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `std::cout::operator<<` returns a reference to the stream.

Next, `std::ostream` has an [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (inherited from `std::basic_ios`):

> Returns true if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns !fail().

Hence, what happens is that `cout << "A"` prints `"A"`, then returns a reference to `std::cout`, this is implciticly converted to `bool`. As `std::cout` is not in an error state it is `true` and `!true` lets the `if` enter the `else` branch.

---

Note that the comment that comes with the code is misleading:

> ```
> // CPP program to verifies the condition inside if block
> // It just verifies the condition inside if block,
> // i.e., cout << "geeks" which returns a non-zero value,
> // !(non-zero value) is false, hence it executes else
> ```

`std::cout` is certainly not `0`, but thats not the reason the condition evaluates to `!true`! The reason is that `std::cout::operator bool` is called to perform the implicit conversion to `bool`.

---

Last but not least, the example is completely silly. It basically says: When the stream is not in a failure state then print something, when it is in a failure state then try to print something anyhow. That does not make much sense. On the other hand, using the implicit conversion to `bool` is common when reading input from the user:

```
if (std::cin >> x) {
    ... use x ...
} else {
    std::cout << "reading input failed";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A follow-up question: is this type of syntax common to find or just a fancy trick one can use ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa I forgot to mention it, the example is rather silly. What is common is `if (std::cin >> x) { ... use x...} else { ..handle invalid input ... }` when you want to read a value and use the value only when reading the value suceeded