# How cin>>x returns bool type value in if(cin>>x) but not while cout<<(cin>>x);

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean, cin

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout<<(std::cin>>x)<<"\n";
    
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    
    if(std::cin>>x)
    {
        std::cout<<"inside the if-block\n";
    }
}
```

**Output-1**

```
2                  // input-1
0x486650
3                 // input-2
inside the if-block
```

for input `2` `cin>>x` succeeds but gives `0x486650`

for input `3` if-block executed means it returns `1`.

**Output-2**

```
a                 // input-1
0
b                 // input-2
```

for input `a` `cin>>x` fails and gives `0` as expected.

for input `b` `cin>>x` if-block not executed means it returns `0`

So why `std::cout<<(std::cin>>x)` returns something like `0x486650` when succeeds ?

Comment: I'm surprised this code even compiled.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: In the `if` block, the `std::ifstream operator bool` is used to give a Boolean value; in the output case, that isn't required, so (I think) it takes the address of the `cin` object, instead. Not sure, though. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62200609/10871073

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  I can only get this code to compile with C++03, which is now a "very old" version of C++.

Comment: What `std::cin >> x` is [returning](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) is actually `std::cin` itself. _In the context of an if statement_, that will get converted to `bool` because it has an [explicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). But when you pass it as an argument to `std::cout << (std::cin >> x);`, you're just trying to `std::cout` the istream. That doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver ide->Devcpp C++11

Comment: @NathanPierson so is it case of Undefined behavior ?

Comment: you're presumably using an ancient compiler so have the c++03 behaviour which returns a null pointer on failure or a non-null pointer (to what isn't specified) if the stream is OK, the value you are seeing is simply the returned pointer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score 3):

Before C++11 streams didn't have an `operator bool()` and had an `operator void*()` instead, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool.

When used as intended i.e.:

```
if (std::cin)
{
}
```

or:

```
if (std::cin >> x)
{
}
```

There is no difference between the C++11 and pre C++11 behaviour.

However if you try to directly print a stream:

```
std::cout<<std::cin;
```

In C++11 this fails to compile as there is no standard stream operator that takes an input stream and the boolean conversion operator is marked as explicit.

In C++03 however the `void*` conversion is not explicit so "printing" an input stream results in the fairly surprising behaviour of printing a pointer. If the stream is in a failed state the pointer will be null so `0` will be printed. If the stream isn't in a failed state the pointer will be non-null (possibly a pointer to the stream itself, this isn't specified by the standard) so will result in a non-zero address being printed. e.g. see https://godbolt.org/z/dM3ce5Kes

Comment: `In C++11 this fails to compile as there is no standard stream operator that takes an input stream and the boolean conversion operator is marked as explicit.`  "the boolean conversion marked as explicit"  what this means exactly I am not getting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean

Comment: but how come it works inside `if(std::cin>>x)` in C++11 as it is marked as explicit because then compiler will not use that `operator bool()` functions implicitly  to convert into `bool`  right ?

Comment: and Also how `non null pointer` and `null pointer` results of `std::cin>>x` inside the `if(std::cin>>x)` convert into bool type ?

Comment: Using an explicit bool operator inside an if statement is allowed. Null pointers convert to false, non-null pointers convert to true